# Erro 381 listbox.list VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, listbox

Olá! Basicamente eu preciso somar os valores da listbox, só que meu programa está apresentando o seguinte erro.

Erro em tempo de execução '381': Não foi possível obter a propriedade List. Índice de matriz de propriedade inválido.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

Dim linhalistbox As Integer
Dim linha As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim soma As Integer

linhalistbox = Me.ListBox1.ListCount
linha = 2
i = 0

Do Until Plan2.Cells(linha, 1) = ""                         'Loop vai rodar ate encontrar uma celula vazia na coluna dos codigos
    If TextBox1.Text = Plan2.Cells(linha, 1) Then           'Se o textbox1(codigo) for igual ao codigo da celula
        With Me.ListBox1
        .AddItem
        .List(linhalistbox, 0) = linhalistbox + 1           'Coluna 1 do listbox = ao contador de linha do listbox
        .List(linhalistbox, 1) = Plan2.Cells(linha, 3)      'Coluna 2 do listbox = ao descrição do produto
        .List(linhalistbox, 2) = Plan2.Cells(linha, 4)      'Coluna 3 do listbox = ao valor do produto
        Do Until Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2) = ""                'ERRO 
            soma = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2) + soma            'Soma os valores dentro das celulas da coluna 2
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        TextBox2.Text = linhalistbox + 1                    'Numero de itens
        TextBox5.Text = Plan2.Cells(linha, 4)               'Mostra o valor do produto
        TextBox6.Text = soma                                'Apresenta o sub total
        linhalistbox = linhalistbox + 1
        End With
    End If
    linha = linha + 1
Loop

TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Em que linha ocorre o erro? Mas provavelmente com [Erro 381](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/invalid-property-array-index-error-381) você está preenchendo a matriz incorretamente e há algum valor vazio. Crie um [mcve] para ficar mais fácil de ajudar, com alguns dados fictícios da [tabela](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: O erro está nesta linha: Do until me.listbox1.list(i,2)=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque não há nenhum item na lista.
Portanto ou você adiciona um item no início da lista e haverá uma linha nula, com:

`Me.ListBox1.AddItem` e verifica se é nulo com: `Do Until IsNull(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2))`

Ou realiza o loop com: `Do Until i = linhalistbox + 1`

#### Código `Do Until IsNull(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2))`

```
Dim linhalistbox As Long
Dim linha As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim soma As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha2")
linhalistbox = Me.ListBox1.ListCount
linha = 2
i = 0
Me.ListBox1.AddItem
Do Until ws.Cells(linha, 1) = ""             'Loop vai rodar ate encontrar uma celula vazia na coluna dos codigos
    If Me.TextBox1.Text = ws.Cells(linha, 1) Then 'Se o textbox1(codigo) for igual ao codigo da celula
        With Me.ListBox1
            .AddItem
            .List(linhalistbox, 0) = linhalistbox + 1 'Coluna 1 do listbox = ao contador de linha do listbox
            .List(linhalistbox, 1) = ws.Cells(linha, 3) 'Coluna 2 do listbox = ao descrição do produto
            .List(linhalistbox, 2) = ws.Cells(linha, 4) 'Coluna 3 do listbox = ao valor do produto
            Do Until IsNull(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2))    'ERRO
                soma = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2) + soma 'Soma os valores dentro das celulas da coluna 2
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            TextBox2.Text = linhalistbox + 1 'Numero de itens
            TextBox5.Text = ws.Cells(linha, 4) 'Mostra o valor do produto
            TextBox6.Text = soma             'Apresenta o sub total
            linhalistbox = linhalistbox + 1
        End With
    End If
    linha = linha + 1
Loop
TextBox1.Text = ""
```

#### Código `Do Until i = linhalistbox + 1`

```
Dim linhalistbox As Long
Dim linha As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim soma As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha2")
linhalistbox = Me.ListBox1.ListCount
linha = 2
i = 0

Do Until ws.Cells(linha, 1) = ""             'Loop vai rodar ate encontrar uma celula vazia na coluna dos codigos
    If Me.TextBox1.Text = ws.Cells(linha, 1) Then 'Se o textbox1(codigo) for igual ao codigo da celula
        With Me.ListBox1
            .AddItem
            .List(linhalistbox, 0) = linhalistbox + 1 'Coluna 1 do listbox = ao contador de linha do listbox
            .List(linhalistbox, 1) = ws.Cells(linha, 3) 'Coluna 2 do listbox = ao descrição do produto
            .List(linhalistbox, 2) = ws.Cells(linha, 4) 'Coluna 3 do listbox = ao valor do produto
            Do Until i = linhalistbox + 1    'ERRO
                soma = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2) + soma 'Soma os valores dentro das celulas da coluna 2
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            TextBox2.Text = linhalistbox + 1 'Numero de itens
            TextBox5.Text = ws.Cells(linha, 4) 'Mostra o valor do produto
            TextBox6.Text = soma             'Apresenta o sub total
            linhalistbox = linhalistbox + 1
        End With
    End If
    linha = linha + 1
Loop
TextBox1.Text = ""
```

Comment: Daniel muito obrigado pelas dicas vou tentar. Grande abraço.